# do libraries get imported/loaded on memory per class created or just once

Tags: java, memory-management

Still learning the basics but I just had a question about libraries, classes and memory.

Hypothetically, say I have 3 classes. Main, child and sub child.

Main creates several child classes, and child creates several sub child classes. If I have an import library in sub child, does it load the library for every sub child several times per sub child class created or does it load it onto the memory only once? I assume the latter as thats ideal and the smart way to go but you cant be sure so hence why I'm here trying to scratch that itch.

Using Java in Netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

> Main creates several child classes

This is incorrect. Or at least, highly doubtful. Creating new *classes* in java code involves invoking `someClassLoader.defineClass(byteCode)`, and to have a bytecode generator library. No doubt that's not what you have.

Perhaps you meant: "The code in my Main class will instantiate several different classes".

> If I have an import library in sub child

This is misleading. In java, `import` does not mean 'fetch this code and run it'. It's an alias. `import java.io.File;` means: "Anytime I mention the simple identifier "File" in this source code file and it is in a position where a type is needed, assume I meant to write 'java.io.File' instead".

import statements do not run any code, and if you import a class that you then do not ever use in your source file, there is absolutely nothing whatsoever left of this import statement in the resulting class file. Absolutely no difference whatsoever. You don't need that imported-but-never-used class at runtime.

> does it load the library

Because of your confusion about terminology I don't really know what you're asking, but the answer to this question regardless of how many caveats you care to pile on is always: "At most once", unless multiple classloaders are involved (which is something you'd have to explicitly code. Multiple entries on the classpath does not mean 'multiple classloaders'. That just means 'a single classloader that will be loading from multiple places on disk'. If you explicitly are adding a bunch of classloader infrastructure to your app, you'd know).